# How to map a promise function to a JSX component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to write some React components as following to map a promise function result to JSX equivalent components?

```
<Promise on={myFunc}>
    <Pending>
        ...
    </Pending>        
    <Resolved>
        {(data: any) => ( ... )}
    </Resolved> 
    <Rejected>
        {(err: any) => ( ... )}
    </Rejected>      
</Promise>
```

- `Pending` component for when the function is executing.
- `Resolved` component with `data` for a resolved situation.
- `Rejected` component with `err` for when we have an error.

Comment: Yes, but have you checked react suspense?

Comment: @DennisVash I don't want to use `Suspense`. I am looking for learning how it is possible by React with the above structure. Can you help me with this and share some snippet codes?

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-tharp-hv1lh?file=/src/App.js)?

Comment: @Yousaf Yesssss

Comment: @Yousaf Is it possible for you to share your link as an answer. It helps others and also I can mark it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Demo i created was just to give you an idea of what you could do. You can answer your own question, showing the solution you implemented. Even if it's the same as my demo, you can post an answer, i won't mind it.

Answer (score 1):

A Promise isn't really a good way to store state for components. You should create a state variable to store the status of the Promise.

```
const SomeComponent = () => {

    const [statusOfThePromise, setStatusOfThePromise] = useState('Pending');

    const someEventHandler = () => {
        const _promise = somePromiseReturningFunction();
        //...

        _promise.then(result => {
              const newPromiseStatus = /* ... */;
              setStatusOfThePromise(newPromiseStatus);
        });
    };

    if(statusOfThePromise === 'Pending') {
         return <div>Promise is pending...</div>;
    }
    else if(statusOfThePromise === 'Error') {
         return <div>Promise returned an error</div>;
    }
    else if(statusOfThePromise === 'Success') {
         return <div>Promise finished successfully</div>;
    }
    else {
         return <div>Invalid promise status</div>;
    }
};
```